# How do I change CodeRush to append the "this" keyword when converting to auto-implemented properties and extract to method refactorings?

Tags: coderush

I like to use the "this" keyword when referencing auto-implemented properties and when calling methods inside my class. How do I change the CodeRush templates for "Convert to auto-implemented property" and "Extract Method" to append the "this" keyword to the refactored references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible at the moment. But, most likely, this ability will appear in the near future.

Comment: Is there a CR issue Id this can link to? (I think it's confusing to have whats effectively this type of thing on SO instead of support.devexpress.com

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding - yes, there is an issue id - we are going to address this issue in the context of the following suggestion: S19229.